# redirection of non-existing folder mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect a certain url request like:

http://sample.org/www/images/animal.png

file structure:

rootpath/images/animal.png

rootpath/www/

Comment: The images folder that do not exist inside www folder. Rather they are both in the same location.

Comment: So you want someone to be able to type `http://sample.org/www/images/animal.png` in their browser's URL address bar, and then redirect them to `http://sample.org/images/animal.png` where the image actually is, thus changing the URL in the address bar to the new URL?

Comment: Not redirect exactly. its more like you have and alias folder of images folder inside www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/www/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^/?www/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that there is a htaccess file on the on the root directory. And it contains RewriteRule (.*) www/$1  [L]. i think this also affecting the 3rd line of your answer.

Comment: @jrsalunga So you're taking a request, and rewriting the URI (e.g. `/images/animal.png`) internally on the server to `/www/images/animal.png`? I thought `/www` was the non-existent folder. Why would you want to point legit requests to a folder that doesn't exist?